# Syntax for traits with generics

Tags: generics, syntax, rust, traits

I've got the following trait:

```
pub trait Stream<T: Read + Write + AsRawFd>: Sized {
    fn new(stream: T) -> Result<Self, Error>;
    fn recv(&mut self) -> Result<Vec<u8>, Error>;
    fn send(&mut self, buf: &[u8]) -> Result<usize, Error>;
}
```

I'd like to create another trait that takes a type that implements `Stream` as parameter in one of the functions, like so:

```
pub trait EventHandler<T: Stream> {
    fn on_data_received(&mut self, stream: T, buffer: Vec<u8>);
    fn on_stream_closed(&mut self, id: u32);
}
```

I've tried several variations on where to put the trait definitions, but I always seem to get the error:

```
error: wrong number of type arguments: expected 1, found 0
```

What is the proper syntax for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify a type parameter on the `<T: Stream>` bound, like this:

```
pub trait EventHandler<T: Stream<U>, U: Read + Write + AsRawFd> {
    fn on_data_received(&mut self, stream: T, buffer: Vec<u8>);
    fn on_stream_closed(&mut self, id: u32);
}
```

You can also write bounds using `where` clauses:

```
pub trait EventHandler<T, U> where
    T: Stream<U>,
    U: Read + Write + AsRawFd
{
    fn on_data_received(&mut self, stream: T, buffer: Vec<u8>);
    fn on_stream_closed(&mut self, id: u32);
}
```

Another option is to use associated types. Define `Stream` like this:

```
pub trait Stream: Sized {
    type T: Read + Write + AsRawFd;

    fn new(stream: Self::T) -> Result<Self, Error>;
    fn recv(&mut self) -> Result<Vec<u8>, Error>;
    fn send(&mut self, buf: &[u8]) -> Result<usize, Error>;
}
```

Then your original definition of `EventHandler` will work.